# Iterate over list with unmatched open braces

Tags: tcl

I have the following code:

```
set m "value {1{0}"
foreach i $m {puts $i}
```

This results in the error "unmatched open brace in list".
Looks like TCL does not consider m to be a valid list due to the unmatched braces. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Lists are subsets of strings in Tcl. You have one of the strings that is not a list. There are multiple ways to make it work, depending on what you expect in various cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid such, errors you should not use "strings" where "lists" are expected. The `foreach` procedure implies a list for its second argument. Your string is incorrect in terms of TCL lists. TCL interpreter is smart, but it doesn't know how to convert this value to the correct list.

The first option is to set the variable as a list:

```
set m [list "value" "{1{0}"]
foreach i $m {puts $i}
```

The second option is convert the sting to a list (split the string by a space in this example):

```
set m "value {1{0}"
set m [split $m " "]
foreach i $m {puts $i}
```

And again, don't use "strings" where "lists" are expected. Strings can be used, but you should fully understand what you are doing and ensure that the string is in the correct format to be converted into a list.